# How can I simulate a (simple) 555 circuit in KiCad?

Tags: 555, spice, kicad

I want to simulate a 555 circuit in KiCad, but quite failing to do so. I found a SPICE model [here](https://kicad-info.s3.dualstack.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/original/3X/5/0/50047e520b1352c6282a3da8bf106c6c29fbecd6.lib) and included it in my model like this:

[image]

My circuit looks like this:

[image]

The transient simulation works. It should oscillate at around 14ms, but it doesn't do so:

[image]

How can I simulate the 555 in KiCad?

**Update** I made the simulation a little longer, and I do get some results, but not quite what I expect:

This is from 3s - 4s:
[image]

And from 4s - 5s:
[image]

Comment: I think that in Kicad 8, that it's at the moment in 'release candidate 2', there are important improvements in simulation.

Comment: Hmmm...looks like the ngspice engine is having trouble with the transistor-based model.  Try adding a SPICE directive to the schematic and see if it helps: `.options cshunt=1p`

Comment: Can also try Gear integration method by doing this:  `.options method=gear`

Answer (score 4):

Did you give it enough time to start? My model does start after ~2.38sec.

I tested with KiCAD 7.0.8

Simulator, Sim Command, Transient tab, 1m in Time step and Final time set to 3 seconds.

[image]

Please see attached picture:

[image]

Zoomed in and more signals - the plot looks  like this:

[image: NE555 simulation]

NE555.lib file downloaded from here: [KiCAD forum](https://forum.kicad.info/t/simulation-of-555-timer-circuit-in-kicad/21697/7)

---**EDIT**---  To check if skipping is present.

This is my result when setup is: transient: 100us step, 3 to 4 second simulation. Voltage seems to be a bit unstable, otherwise fine (no skips).

[image: 100micro-3secto4sec]

Other setup: 10us step, other parameters the same.

[image: 10microsec-3secto4sec]

And the last one: 1us step.

[image: 1microsec-3secto4sec]

Comment: Thanks, I got it almost... Ran it in KiCAD 7.0.10, see my updated question. Your results are significantly better.

Comment: @BartFriederichs Perhaps skip the initial operating point analysis for the transient simulation, by including the "UIC" argument. For example ".tran 1m 1 uic"

Comment: @SimonFitch skipping is OK, problem I still have is the results vary even after that initial startup time.

Comment: @Bart Friederichs I see your skipping. Also, your voltage levels are somehow uneven. Let me check this on my simulation. I see the .lib files are identical.

Answer (score 0):

> it should oscillate at around 14ms, but it doesn't do so:

It should be 35 ms ... Simulated with [microcap v12](https://archive.org/details/mc12cd_202110).

[image]

Comment: The problem is not with the circuit, but with KiCad. I have successfully simulated it with other tools. I want to use KiCad because my other designs are in there as well.

Comment: Don't know KiCad. Ok, but the period should be 35 ms, not 14 ms ...

Comment: @BartFriederichs The problem is with NgSpice that KiCad uses as the SPICE engine. The KiCad project has not developed their own simulator yet :)